# Tips for determining/debugging C++ buildbox differences

Tags: c++, gcc, build, c-preprocessor

**The premise**

- A clean Ubuntu 14.04 box, I add build-essentials, gcc-4.7
- A clean Debian 7 box, I add build-essentials, gcc-4.7

On each platform, I build a static library `libFoo.a` using the same source code and make file.

---

**The problem**

When building a simple program (on a third build box), and linking with `libFoo.a`, the program behaves differently depending on whether the library came from the Ubuntu-, or Debian-box.

The build of `libFoo.a` does not link to any library on the build box. The difference would have to come from any of the header files included in the build. (For example, `libc6-dev` is version `2.19` on ubuntu, and `2.13` on debian).

---

**The question**

What method would you suggest for determining the source of the difference(s) between the two build boxes that is causing the difference in behavior?

---

**The partial solution (?)**

When using the `-E`-flag, `gcc` outputs the preprocessor output, which seems like a step in the right direction. It shows where each section comes from, e.g.

```
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h" 1 3 4
```

Manually bisecting and determining the source seems to be possible (though, very tedious, and error prone). Is there a better way?

---

Also, the `-E` flag tells `gcc` to stop after the precompiler step. How do I tell it to continue, using a modified precompiler step output?

---

Maybe one way to do this is to make a copy of all the external header files that are used, put them somewhere `gcc` first looks, so that I can control absolutely every line of code that the preprocessor uses. After that, swap out files with the equivalent files in the other build-box, until the `libFoo.a` behavior is the same. It might also impossible, since there are probably a lot of inter-header-file dependencies.

To do this, it would certainly help to know how to get `gcc` to not look anywhere it usually does, for includes.

---

Thoughts, ideas?

Comment: *"the program behaves differently"* -- you can write **unit tests** which ensure the defined behavior. Then you'll see where the problem is coming from (those test(s) are going to fail). This is not a real answer, however it helps very much if such porting issues occur.

Comment: The difference in behavior is general. In my case, it is not far from it being a unit test that failed. Having now caught the failure, I'm trying to determine the cause of it. Nevertheless, it is absolutely a good thing to have unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Since all differences mentioned were part of include files otherwise in the system, one solution is to make a local copy of all the include paths `gcc` looks into.

To determine which paths are searched, use `gcc -xc -E -v -`. Then reverse the ordering (so that in case of overrides, it follows the same matching priority as gcc), and copy all the paths' contents to a local dir, `MAGICINCLUDE`.

The following does this work:

```bash
#/bin/bash
tmp_file=$(tempfile)
(gcc -xc -E -v - 2> "$tmp_file" 1>/dev/null) & pid=$!
sleep 0.4
if ps -p $pid > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    kill -9 $pid > /dev/null 2>&1
fi

paths=$(sed -n '/> search starts here/,/End of search list./p' $tmp_file \
               | head -n -1 | tac | head -n -1)
rm $tmp_file

if [ ! -d MAGICINCLUDE ] ; then mkdir MAGICINCLUDE ; fi
while read path ; do
    if [ "$(ls -1 $path | wc -l)" -gt 0 ] ; then
        cp -r $path/* MAGICINCLUDE/
    fi
done <<< "$paths"
```

After running this on the build box that produced the correct behavior of `libFoo.so`, copy `MAGICINCLUDE` to the build box that produced the wrong behavior.

Add the include flag `-IMAGICINCLUDE` (or whatever variation it takes) before all others, and `gcc` will first try to find a match within the `MAGICINCLUDE` folder structure.

If this **fixes** the problem with `libFoo.a` when built on the bad build box, then you are on the right track. This means that something you copied from the working build box (that you now have complete control over), now fixes the problem.

By also placing `MAGICINCLUDE` under revision control (e.g. `cd MAGICINCLUDE && git init && git add . && git commit -m "n/a"`), you can easily delete and undelete from `MAGICINCLUDE`, headers that you suspect might be the cause. Continue until build creates the initial broken `libFoo.a`, then narrow down which include(s) from `MAGICINCLUDE` is the cause of change.

Note: If deleting some of the files causes a compile error, the result has to be ignored, as this is due broken dependencies between header files.

---

*Bonus:* to better determine which files can be problematic, you can investigate which headers are included in a particular compilation using `-E`, and grepping all header file paths.

```
gcc -E [...] | grep -oP '".*\.h"'  | sed 's/"//g' | sort | uniq
```

In my particular example, the problem was with sockets, so I quickly deleted all header includes (from the output of the above command) that contained the word socket. And reduced the problem source from 2346 files, to 14. After narrowing it down to one line of code, it was then made obvious what in the source of `libFoo.a`, that actually was the problem.

---